# Access integer in one class from another

Tags: java

So I am trying to call my integer from one class to another

My first class is

```
class myclock {
    private int hour;
    private int min;
}
```

and my second class

```
class repair {
    int foward() {
    }
}
```

in my second class I am trying call the value of hour and min from my first class so how would I do that?

This is what i have done already

```
myclock hour = new myclock();
int t = hour.value;
```

but it keeps giving me error so I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: no we have to keep it private

Comment: Do not give advices like that. public instance variables are an antipattern in java.

Comment: Then make a method. `public int getValue() { return value; }`

Comment: You may need to take time to learn basics of Java, you would learn all the things which you're asking :)

Comment: @AdamArold well having such class names is an antipattern too.

Comment: `myclock hour = new myclock();` hour is an object of type `myclock`. To access the fields of this object you need to use: `hour.hour` or `hour.min`. As said in other coments, the fields are private, so create a getter method in the myclock class or change it to public.

Comment: @kevintjuh93 No, lowercase class names are not an anti-pattern, they are just against the typical Java naming convention. An anti-pattern actually affects how the code is structured - changing access modifiers would fall into this category. Changing a class name does not.

Answer (score 2):

In java this is usually solved with using getters:

```
public class MyClock {
    private int hour;
    private int min;

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }
}
```

Please note that classes in java are camel case with the first letter being capital (like in my example).

Please also note that the keyword `private` - as the name suggests - makes a symbol private so it is not accessible for the outside world.

Answer (score -1):

Add a constructor and possibly some getter or setter functions to your class. You cannot access it from outside the class because it is marked as `private`.

```
class MyClock {
  private int hour;
  private int min;

  //Constructor
  public MyClock(int hour, int min){
    this.hour = hour;
    this.min = min;
  }

  // Getter method
  public int getHour(){
    return hour;
  }
  // Setter method
  public void setHour(int hour){
    this.hour = hour;
  }  
}
```

now you can run this from the main method or from another class:

```
MyClock mc = new MyClock(12,0);
// currentHour will be assigned the value 12
int currenthour = mc.getHour();
```

Answer (score -1):

As you see, you declare these variables as `private` but then you're trying to access them directly. That's the problem. You can change it to `public` to make them available for outside but that is a violation of encapsulation. 
Best practice is providing a `getter` for these variables.

I suggest you to read about object oriented programming and learn the basics.